# AutoHotKey on right mouse click get a keyboard button pressed as well

Tags: autohotkey, mousedown

Could someone help me with AutoHotKey Macro to have Q button pressed and released when right mouse button is clicked and Q button pressed and released when right mouse button is released?

Edit:

Explanation, imagine, that I am playing a game, and when i click right mouse button down (then I hold it) i need to have Q letter auto pressed on the keyboard, so I would get a jump(or crouch) in game at that time and when i release the right mouse button (mouse button up) i would get Q auto pressed again.
I was trying to write the script and I couldn't get it working.

This is what I came up so far:

```
    RButton::
    If !Toggler {
    Send, {RButton Down} q
    Return
    }
    Send {RButton Up} q
    Return
```

Comment: Could you try to rewrite your question as it is not very clear what you want! What do you mean with Q button? Is this a software button with a Q? or do you mean the Q key?

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK it looks like you want to toggle the behaviour.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Make search title in #IfWinActive more flexible

#IfWinActive, Title of your game as found by AHK Windows Spy 
    RButton::
        If (Toggler := !Toggler )
        {
            ToolTip, RButton Down
            Send, {RButton Down} q
            Return
        }
        ToolTip, RButton Up        
        Send {RButton Up} q
    Return
#IfWinActive
Return

*x::
ExitApp
```

## Update

After reading your text (and ignoring your script where you want to toggle the behaviour), I think that you want this! `RightClick` will send `RightClick Down + q`, then nothing, until you let go of `RightClick`, which will then send a `RightClick Up + q`. I added the ToolTips, so you can see if the script is activated correctly by #IfWinActive.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Make search title in #IfWinActive more flexible

#IfWinActive, Title of your game as found by AHK Windows Spy

RButton::
    ToolTip, RButton Down + q
    Send, {RButton Down} q
Return

RButton Up::
    ToolTip, RButton Up + q
    Send, {RButton Up} q
Return

#IfWinActive
Return

*x::
ExitApp
```

If this is indeed what you want, then the final solution is coming pretty close to the original tip from Armin!

## Update 2, Alternative way

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Make search title in #IfWinActive more flexible

#IfWinActive, Title of your game as found by AHK Windows Spy
    *~RButton:: ; ~ passes Rbutton through
        ToolTip, RButton Down + q
        Send, q
        KeyWait, RButton ; Wait for RButton to be released
        ToolTip, RButton Up + q
        Send, q
    Return
#IfWinActive
Return

*x::
ExitApp
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as I'll get back home. By the way, what should be added so this script will only be active in specific game, so i could just add path to file or something?

Comment: Yeah, the updated script looks more of correct one. I will try it and will inform how it goes. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: I am now using the 2nd variant of the script, while everything works as expected, there is one unpleasant thing - sometimes a small white rectangle with black on white text "RButton Up + q" is getting visible in various places in game, and it starts to annoy :) Is there something that i should turn off in AutoHotKey or this is script related?

Comment: Just remove these two lines with `ToolTip` from the code. These lines were only added, so you could verify that the script worked

Comment: I found one think when using your AutoHotLey script (Update 2, Alternative way) There is a problem for the right mouse click to activate the Q key if there is a shift button pressed on the keyboard. So if shift is pressed and I then press right mouse click the script doesn't work. If W A S D keys are pressed before mouseclick - it works fine. Is there some workaround? Also, sometimes the compiled exe file closes itself. Why would that happen?

Comment: @CamSpy, I added an asterisk in front of the ~RButton. The `*` allows the RButton hotkey to be triggered with or without any modifier key. Hope this helps! Not sure why the .exe would close. It could be because I placed an ExitApp on the letter x (with any modifier key combination). Remove the last two lines of code or replace *x with a unique combination (e.g. `^!+#x`= [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Shift]+[Win]+[x])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the suffix `up` wit a hotkey.

Example

```
h up::
    ; your code
return
```

Will trigger when you release key `h`. You can use this with any hotkey including mouse.

You can use [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command for sending key presses.